# How to restore jquery dialog with minimze

Tags: jquery, dialog

I am trying to programatically click the restore button.

```
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="white-space: nowrap;"><span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-module_scheduler" style="overflow: hidden; width: 112.21875px;"><img src="imgs/omButtons/omIcon.png" border="0" height="18"> Office Schedule</span><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar-buttonpane" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; right: 0.3em; margin-top: -10px; height: 18px;"><a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button" style="position: static; top: auto; right: auto; margin: 0px;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a><a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-maximize ui-corner-all" href="#" role="button" style="display: block;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-extlink">maximize</span></a><a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-restore ui-corner-all" href="#" role="button" style="display: block; right: 2.5em;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-newwin">restore</span></a><a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-minimize ui-corner-all" href="#" role="button" style="display: none;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minus">minimize</span></a></div></div>
```

I have

```
$('div [aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-module_scheduler"]').find('a .ui-dialog-titlebar-restore').click();
```

However i am not a jQuery expert so i am guessing the syntax is wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('div[aria-labelledby=ui-dialog-title-module_scheduler]').find('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-restore').click();
```

Remove spaces and quotes, did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you try `$('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-restore .ui-icon).click(function() {});`?

Comment: That wont work because it will apply to ALL restore dialog buttons. I posted the resolution an hour ago. Thanks.

Comment: I thinks just provide a class for parent element of this, it will be become unique in your dom. $('.[parent-class-name] a.ui-dialog-titlebar-restore .ui-icon)